# How to remove false directory created in my project folder when using Python virtual environment in Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Every time I create a Python virtual environment it creates  a 'false' directory in my project directory. what is it for? Its messing my contribution to open source. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: I remember seeing this. Was a bug in user `pip.conf` — some option that must be a directory was `false`. Please show your `pip config list`

Comment: global.cache-dir='false'. That is the result of pip config list

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Two problems, actually. 1st, `'false'` is a string, not a bool; a bool is just `false`, no quotes. 2nd, `global.cache-dir` must not be `false`. Remove it from config: `pip config unset global.cache-dir`

Answer (score 1):

`pip config unset global.cache-dir` command solved this issue as mentioned by @phd in comment.
Thanks